# On row click , prevent to redirect when clicking on the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am using data table
Row click I want to do something [redirection],
in a row, one of the columns has a button & it has some action.

Problem: when I click button to do action getting row click, want to prevent row click while clicking on button

**CODE**

```
$('#example').click(function () {
  var dataArr;
  var rows = $('tr.selected');
  var rowData = table.rows(rows).data();
  $.each($(rowData), function (key, value) {
    dataArr = value["id"];
    window.location = 'clients?id=' + dataArr;
  });
}
```

What should I change? Thank you

Edit:

The buttons :

```
    $(document)
        .ready(
            function() {
                var table = $('#example')
                    .DataTable({
                        "sAjaxSource": "/clients",
                        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
                        "order": [
                            [0, "asc"]
                        ],

                        "aoColumns": [{
                                "mData": "id"
                            },
                            {
                                "mData": "name"
                            },
                            {
                                "mData": "lastName"
                            },

                            {
                                "mData": null,
                                defaultContent:'<p>1</p>'
                            },


                            {
                                "mData": null,
                                className: "center",
                                defaultContent: '<a href="clients.html"> <p title="New"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs newButton" data-title="Add"  id="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></p></a>'
                            },
                            {
                                "mData": null,
                                className: "center",
                                defaultContent: '<p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit "><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs data-title="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p>'
                            },
                            {
                                "mData": null,
                                className: "center",
                                defaultContent: '   <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p>'
                            }

                        ]

                    });
```

I am using DataTables. ANd only need this for the last two columns where edit and delete are

Comment: can you recreate the problem in a snippet.

Comment: The buttons, are they `a` tags or `<button>`

Comment: You need to show us your markup/generated-markup.

Comment: I edited my question, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever child event call parent event, here you can prevent using the following method.

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `event.stopPropagation();`

The code will be similar with :

```
$(".table_row"/*the table row class*/).on('click', 'button', function () {
         //button action 
     }).on('click', $(this).parent().parent().parent() , function (e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
     });/* if  $(this).parent().parent().parent() doesn't work ,search in developer tools to see where click action is triggered ,on the */
```

Something like [image: this]

I tried to make something I don't know if you like it but it works the way you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w1wge78u/1/)(updated).